# Ansible: extract archive to user's dir

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to build an ansible playbook which extracts an archive (available through http) under a folder to be created in the user's home directory.
So far I've come up with:

```
- name: Extract archive
  unarchive:
          creates: wildfly
          src: "http://download.jboss.org/wildfly/10.1.0.Final/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.zip"
          dest: "{{ ansible_user_dir }}"/wildfly
          remote_src: yes
```

However by running it, I get a syntax error: here is the offending line:

```
dest: "{{ ansible_user_dir }}"/wildfly
                              ^ here
```

I've tried also without quotes, but the issue stays the same.
By hardcoding the user's home dir it works- except that no folder "wildfly" is created. Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the whole expression:

```
dest: "{{ ansible_user_dir }}/wildfly"
```

Comment: Thanks! that moved me on. However it seems that the folder "wildfly" wasn't created: "dest '/root/wildfly' must be an existing dir". Is my understanding correct that "creates" should create the folder if it doesn't exist? Thanks

Comment: "creates" refers to the destination file, not to the target directory. To make the directory add a task file with state=directory, something like  - file: path={{ ansible_user_dir }}/wildfly state=directory mode=0755

Comment: Thanks, just did it. It works:
file: path="{{ ansible_user_dir }}/wildfly" state=directory